# How to run a script after receiving a file from scp

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I want to run a script to process every file received via scp protocol in a certain directory, immediately after it's received.

I do not want to pool that directory, in order to avoid trying to process a file partially received. This is also the problem that prevent's me from using inotify tools (https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki), I guess, because I have no way to know if a file was closed after a successful transfer, or if it was closed prematurely

Comment: maybe you also need to transfer a checksum file to verify that the received file is complete.

Comment: not a possibility in my case, because I have no control over the side that will initiate the transfers

Comment: If you want a solution that isn't a hack, you should look at one of the commercial SSH/SCP/SFTP servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you don't have access to client side (my previous answer), you can configure server using ForceCommand option, example:

```
ForceCommand $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND && run_script.sh
```

but this is not failproof, it will break normal ssh connections and it is little more like hack ...

Comment: This one looks interesting. I'll try it as soon as possible to see if I can make it work

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, it is a pretty good hack, but hard to set up.

You have to use undocumented options in scp: -f and -t (see scp.c).

On remote server which receive scp command:

1. in /etc/password, you have to replace /bin/bash by a shell script
2. Shell script have to get parameters received from client (see special parameters $@)
3. in shell script, you choose directory where you want to send file you are transfering
4. in shell script execute scp -r -p -t /new/directory   in scp code, -t initializes iamremote variable which allows transfering from current connection.
5. in shell script execute some actions after this, or not
6. exit

For getting file, replace -t by -f

I am currently working on such a shell script and it is working fine since years.

More information about these options: 
https://lists.gt.net/openssh/dev/41493?do=post_view_threaded
https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way of doing so with pure scp. I would recommend handling this in some ssh-level using commands, like this:

```
cat local_file | ssh user@host "tee > /path/to/remote_file && run_script.sh"
```

If you have access to client side, it is the most easy way of doing so. Basically scp doesn't do anything more complicated than this, but it is encapsulated in nice small command.